# Bash script to select filename with latest date and without substring

Tags: string, bash, shell, ubuntu, filenames

If a directory `/dat` contains files with filenames such as

```
base-2020-01-01.dat
base-2020-01-01-incremental-2020-01-02.dat
base-2020-01-01-incremental-2020-01-03.dat
base-2020-01-03.dat
base-2020-01-03-incremental-2020-01-04.dat
base-2020-01-03-incremental-2020-01-05.dat
```

how can we write a bash script that selects

- the `base-*.dat` filename without the `-incremental-*` substring, and whose date in the filename is the most recent one.
- the date string in this filename

In this example, we want to select `base-2020-01-03.dat` and `2020-01-03`.

*If a different file naming convention makes it easier to parse, that will be even better!*

Comment: That naming convention, assuming YYYY-MM-DD, is absolutely perfect; just a plain ASCII sort will put things in the right order, so standard UNIX tools (`sort`, `grep`, and either `head` or `tail`) will do perfectly.

Comment: One thing that could make it easier is to keep the full backups in one directory (`/dat/full`) and the incremental ones in another (`/dat/inc`). You could then find them like this: `latest_full=$(ls /dat/full | tail -1)` and `latest_inc=$(ls /dat/inc | tail -1)`

Comment: `find dat -type f -name '????-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].dat -printf '%f\n'` with GNU find?, not a solution but just a start

Answer (score 4):

With modern `GNU` tools: Using `find`, `grep -P` and `bash` (with error handling)

```
read file < <(
  find /data -maxdepth 1 -name 'base*.dat' ! -name '*incremental*' \
    -printf '%f\n' | sort -nr | head -n1
)
set -e
echo "${file:?$(tput setaf 1)no match$(tput sgr0;exit 1)}"
date=$(grep -oP "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" <<< "$file")
echo "$date"
```

## Output

```
base-2020-01-03.dat
2020-01-03
```

Comment: `[[ $file =~ .*([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}).* ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"` no grep?

Comment: IINM you are just picking the first file output by find. `find` does not ensure any specific ordering. You cannot assume the first file found is the most recent one according to its name.

Comment: My answer? No, filename expansion automatically sorts the result.

Comment: I tried 'extglob', this is not the _straightforward way_ to do the thing. I think 'find' is more kind of _natural_

Comment: ... and feel 'find' is more _reliable_

Answer (score 3):

Using pure `bash` extended globs and parameter expansion, with no external programs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
declare -a files=(base-!(*incremental*).dat)
echo "Non-incremental files: ${files[*]}"
justdate="${files[-1]#base-}"
justdate="${justdate%.dat}"
echo "Most recent file: ${files[-1]} from $justdate"
```

Usage:

```
$ ls
base-2020-06-29.dat  base-2020-06-30-incremental-2020-07-01.dat  base-2020-07-01.dat  demo.sh
$ bash demo.sh
Non-incremental files: base-2020-06-29.dat base-2020-07-01.dat
Most recent file: base-2020-07-01.dat from 2020-07-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution:

```
date=$(find /dat -name 'base-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].dat' -printf '%f\n' | sort -r | grep -o '[0-9][^.]*' -m1)

[ -n "$date" ] && echo "$date base-$date.dat"
```

- `find` outputs the list of all the files named base-YYYY-MM-DD.dat
- `sort -r` sorts the list with the most recent date first
- `grep -o` extracts the date part and with `-m1` stops at the first line

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU tools to allow NULL delimiter for the sake of paranoia (so a filename with literal newlines can't introduce garbage into your logic -- or at least, won't do anything untoward unless it sorts last):

```
printf '%s\0' /data/base-*.dat |
  sort --zero-terminated |
  grep --null -v incremental |
  tail --zero-terminated -n 1
```

If you aren't on a GNU platform (you don't have all the `--zero-terminated` or `--null` options), change the `\0` to `\n` in the `printf` format string, and remove the aforementioned options.

Comment: Hi Charles, not the required format: file + date. Good advice, but never seen a file with newline in real life since almost 20 years of Linux computing (my 2 cents)

Comment: @GillesQuenot, I've seen files created with names from random memory that a buffer overflow dumped in the wrong place. That one was the cause of the big real-world data loss issue I talk about repeatedly. Doing defensive programming well means being ready for _all_ possible inputs, even the unlikely ones. (Also, if I'm on the red team trying to figure out how to use a system's preexisting cron jobs -- maybe, to cause them to `rm` the wrong thing and thus delete some logs to cover my tracks -- better believe I'm going to think about how they manage filenames with newlines).